# Find a subgroup of index $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}^*_{13}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Find a subgroup of index $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}^*_{13}$. I know that the subgroup must be of order 4, and that the identity has to be in it. Also, every element in the subgroup must have an inverse in the subgroup.

Comment: Find an element $g$ of order $12$, then take $\langle g^3\rangle$.

Comment: how would he find the element of order 12?

Comment: the primitive root is 6 while 3 is of order 4. He would find the element of order 4 before finding the element of order 12.

Comment: Easier: Choose any quadratic nonresidue $g$, then take $\langle g^3\rangle$.

Comment: Or, find an element $g$ such that $g^2 = -1$ (which is indeed a quadratic residue). Then $\langle g \rangle$ has order $4$. Squaring the elements $1,2,\ldots,6$ and taking module $13$ shouldn't be a problem (note that $(p-k)^2 \equiv k^2 (\bmod. p)$ , so we don't have to check $7,\ldots,12$).

Answer (score 2):

Subgroup generated by 8 (or 5) seems to have four elements in it H={[1],[5],[8],[12]}. Identity is there, 12 is self-inverse, 5 and 8 are inverses of each other.

Comment: "Seems"? Since $\;5^2=8^2=-1\pmod{13}\;$ , then for sure $\;|\langle 5\rangle|=|\langle 8\rangle|=4\;$ . In fact, $\;\langle 5\rangle=\langle 8\rangle \;$ +1

Comment: You are so picky on linguistic nuances;), Don.